# Make the tooltip of the Kendo ui slider always visible

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

does anyone knows how I can make the Tooltip over the slider always visible and does not disapear? By default the Tooltip from the kendo slider is hidden and only appears when some interaction has occurred.

Comment: Hello, if somebody wants to play with it, here is [simple sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FsM2j/). Imho the best way to make it always visible is to request this new option from the developers.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without you posting any example code..
I had a quick look at there website and adding this to your css should keep the tooltip displayed at all times.

```
.k-tooltip { display: block !important; }
```

Comment: Hm, 
this doesnt works,  because the toooltip comes via Javascript at the bottom of the body tag and when it disappears the node will be removed...